# Solve the Volterra type integral equation

Tags: integration, integral-equations

> Solve the integral equation $\displaystyle \int_0^x(1-x^2+t^2)\phi(t)\,dt=\frac{x^2}{2}$.

On differentiation, we get 
$$\phi(x)=x+2\int_0^x x\phi(t)\,dt.$$

I'm unable to find resolvent kernal so that I can solve. Also not able to put it in convolution form. How can I proceed further?

Comment: How to get $\phi(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+2x\int_0^x\phi(t)\,dt$? The derivative of LHS is $(1-2x^2)\phi(x)-2x\int_0^x\phi(t)\,dt$ and the derivative of RHS is $x$.

Comment: @FengShao Sorry..!! There was a typo in question. Now fixed !

Comment: Now you get $\phi(x)=x+\int$ rather than $\frac {x^2}{2}$...

Comment: Ohh shit..!! Again fixed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\neq 0$ rewrite
\begin{equation*}
 \phi(x)=x+2\int_{0}^{x}x\phi(t)\,dt
\end{equation*}
as
\begin{equation*}
 \psi(x)=1+2\int_{0}^{x}t\psi(t)\,dt\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where $\psi(x) = \dfrac{\phi(x)}{x}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\psi(x) = 1$.
Differentiation of $(1)$ yields 
\begin{equation*}
 \psi'(x)=2x\psi(x) \Longleftrightarrow \psi(x) = Ce^{x^2}.
\end{equation*}
According to the limit $C=1.$

Consequently
\begin{equation*}
 \phi(x) = xe^{x^2}
\end{equation*}
which satisfies the original integral equation.

Comment: When $\psi(x)=\phi(x)/x$ then how integral becomes $t\psi(t)$ ? Not getting this. Can you please explain this?

Comment: If we start with
\begin{equation*}
 \phi(x)=x+2\int_{0}^{x}x\phi(t)\,dt
\end{equation*}
and then divide with $x$ we get
\begin{gather*}
  \dfrac{\phi(x)}{x} = 1 + 2\int_{0}^{x}\phi(t)\, dt\\
  \psi(x) = 1 + 2\int_{0}^{x}t\cdot\dfrac{\phi(t)}{t}\, dt\\
   \psi(x) = 1 + 2\int_{0}^{x}t\cdot\psi(t)\, dt
 \end{gather*}

Comment: Very nice approach. Great.

Answer (score 1):

*HINT*-As Claude Leibovici suggested to get $$\phi ''(x)-2 x \phi '(x)-4 \phi (x)=0$$

Multiply by $x$ to observe $x\phi''(x)=d(2x^2\phi(x))$

Integrate to get $2x^2\phi(x)=x\phi'(x)-\phi(x)$

or $(2x^2+1)\phi(x)=x\phi'(x)\implies\frac{\phi'(x)}{\phi(x)}=(2x+1/x)\implies In(\phi(x))=x^2+In(x)+a, etc$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for a start**

Starting with $$\displaystyle \int_0^x(1-x^2+t^2)\,\phi(t)\,dt=\frac{x^2}{2}$$ differentiate a first time with respect of $x$ to get
$$-2x\int_0^x  \phi (t) \, dt+\phi (x)=x$$ Do it again
$$-2\int_0^x  \phi (t) \, dt+\phi '(x)-2 x \phi (x)=1$$ and again
$$\phi ''(x)-2 x \phi '(x)-4 \phi (x)=0$$

Comment: Sorry..! There was a typo in question..Please see now. It fixed

Comment: .Ok. After that how can I solve that differential equation ?

Comment: @Empty. I wrote *for a start*. I suppose that there is a change of function which could allow reduction of order. Try WA.